# Execute multiple cron jobs on a single PHP function

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a PHP function in my script which is executed by a cron job defined at server level. When a large amount of data is to be fetched using cron job, than this take much time to complete.

Now, **I want to optimize my cron job to minimize the time**.

Right now I have 30 users and fetch data against all users with single cron job.

Is there better way to do this or should I define 30 cron jobs for each user which hit same function and collect the data ?

Comment: Maybe you can do it in multiple time so instead of doing 30 user every 1h for example, add some "LIMIT" to you query and do 5 user every 20 min for example, no ? Just add some "last_cron" field in your database (datetime) to know who you need to fetch !

Comment: What will be the result if 30 cron jobs executed asynchronously and hit same php class function? Will function break or overwrite the values of each cron job data?